# Converting UK latitude longitude to easting northing

Tags: r, gis, spatial, utm, wgs84

I have been through lots of similar looking questions but still struggling with a solution. I need to convert latitude longitude (in degrees decimal) to easting northing, using R.

All of the co-ordinates are in the UK. I tried to convert to EPSG:27700 for BNG, but it did not come back correctly. When using EPSG:32629 for zone 29 co-ordinates, it is still not right.

With the following example, the converted co-ordinates should be (234734, 107454) and (374359, 162700), but I get this:

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)

xy <- data.frame(ID = 1:2, X = c(51.36277976, 50.842948), Y = c(-2.36967634, -4.3487549))
coordinates(xy) <- c("X", "Y")    
proj4string(xy) <-  CRS("+init=epsg:4326")   
res1 <- spTransform(xy, CRS("+init=epsg:32629"))    
res

           coordinates ID
1 (8981947, -534307.8)  1
2 (8820683, -960825.1)  2

res2 <- spTransport(xy, CRS("+init=epsg:27700"))
res2

          coordinates ID
1 (7446910, -5968181)  1
2 (7322069, -6324791)  2
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm going to guess you have lat and lon switched going into the process

Comment: Yes, you are right! Literally spent hours going in circles with this and it was that simple. Thank you so much!